# how to return client_id from Map using Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this json client:

```
    {
        "StatusCode": 0,
        "StatusMessage": "OK",
        "StatusDescription": [
            {
                "client_id": "123",
                "client_name": "0prVDhbp",
              },
            {
                "client_id": "5876856",
                "client_name": "GKlG1hbp",
            },
              ....
            {
                "client_id": "6896868",
                "client_name": "name",
            }
     ]
  }
```

I used Map for get input value:

```
  _data = new Map<string, any>();

  getData(key) {
    console.log(this._data) // this return only client_name
    return this._data.get(key);
  }
```

How to return client_id not client_name ??

And in component I used `getData()` like this:

```
  let client_id = '';
    if (this.ss.getData('client_id')) {
      client_id = this.ss.getData('client_id');

    }
```

I get all client with this function:

```
this.cs.getAllClients().subscribe(
  client => {
    this.client = client.map((clients) => {
      this.filteredOptionsClient = this.client_id.valueChanges.pipe(
        startWith(''),
        map(val => this.filterClient(val))
      );
      return new Client(clients);
    });
    if (this.ss.getData('client_id')) {
      const client_id = this.ss.getData('client_id');
      this.addsale.controls.client_id.setValue(client_id)
      let selectedClient = new Client('')
      this.selectedClient = null;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.client.length; i++) {
        if (this.client[i].clientName === client_id) {
          this.selectedClient = this.client[i];
        }
      }
    }
  }
);
```

In this part  `if (this.client[i].clientName === client_id) {` my clientName compared with client_id, and is true. When I have a lot of clients with the same name, the clients are frustrated. For this I want to compared with client_id, not name.

Comment: what you got in  this.client and client_id ???

Comment: this.client from `client: Client[];`

Comment: and client_id is from `(this.ss.getData('client_id'))`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 let client= {
            "StatusCode": 0,
            "StatusMessage": "OK",
            "StatusDescription": [
                {
                    "client_id": "123",
                    "client_name": "0prVDhbp",
                  },
                {
                    "client_id": "5876856",
                    "client_name": "GKlG1hbp",
                },
                  ....
                {
                    "client_id": "6896868",
                    "client_name": "name",
                }
         ]
      }

    for(let index in client['StatusDescription']){
       console.log(client['StatusDescription'][index]['client_id'])
    }
```

Comment: I add in my post function that getall clients from Api. Thank you!

Comment: Have you any idea please?